# Why does the R.java file disappear after a few cleans?

Tags: android

I understand that the R.java file is important for mostly a lot of functions in android. So I learned that the way to gte around this is to Clean your project after creating a new android application project. But after a few cleans and you have a lot of code, the R.java file disappears and you are left with an error-ridden `MainActivity.java` file!

I HAVE NO ERROR IN MY XML FILES. And that is why I am really confused. The only error in my package/project folder is in the `MainActivity.java`

Any ideas how to get around this?

I am using Eclipse for making Android Applications, but more stable IDE suggestions for creating android applications would also be appreciated!

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Quote"
/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/Quote"
android:inputType="text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/go"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/press"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/genRan"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/genRan"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: R.java disappears whenever there is an error in the code...

Comment: have you tried with rebuild of your project ?

Comment: I tried BUilding and Cleaning multiple times. It still does not generate

Comment: Try cleaning project, restart eclipse, and clean it again. Sometimes Eclipse is a bit goofy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your project , R.java will be regenerated, If its still not generated, Clean project and check your XML files and code thoroughly if there is any error in resource xml files R.java will not be generated.

Also check that have you import packagename.R in your imports or not?

Comment: I imported it but it returns an error. I think it says that the file does not exist.

Comment: then there must be some error in your res folder ? check throughly the layout hierarchy and every thing ? also check source folder files?

Comment: NO error in my res folder whatsoever only in the MainActivity.java. I have posted my xml file. Maybe there is something wrong there? But there is no error tracked by Eclipse

Comment: there seems no error in xml, u should try cleaning and rebuilding and also restart eclipse

Comment: I have :) And I don't know how I just a dded a few more strings in the Strings.xml and it generated the R.java file. Well, I just checked it thoroughly and compared it to other running applications online :)

Answer (score 1):

in Eclipse `Right click on your project->Build Project` it will create R.java file again

Answer (score 1):

Due to some error it used to happen..

Don't import  com.example.R  .clean your project and try again then restart...try for two three times clean and build , you will get

Answer (score 1):

The `R.java` file is generated by eclipse. So by cleaning the projects, eclipse eliminates all the generated file again to be parallel with the changes you made.

However, the `R.java` file will not generate if there is error on you `res` folder. Better check your `res` folder.

If the problem presist, check your imports. If there aren't any, add an import

`import packagename.R;` OR `import android.R`

Answer (score 1):

This class is automatically generated and should only disappear if you have some fatal errors in your project.

The errors are visible in Eclipse console and error messages. A common problem, some errors may be reported to console but do not show as usual error messages. In some cases (bug probably) empty files with .out.xml extension may appear there, these also break the build.

Check for empty and broken xml files between resources.

With typical default settings, the project should be rebuild automatically after cleanup or any change in your code, unless you twisted Eclipse settings very much in your way.